# Date_part does not works in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT 
 DATE_PART('days',DATE_TRUNC('month', pr.DateTo)  '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - DATE_TRUNC('month', pr.datefrom) as PeriodDays
 FROM HT_PayReg
```

This works well in postgres,but in oracle it does not works,Please correct it in oracle.

Comment: At least you could tell us the purpose of this statement! Not everyone is familiar with postgres!

Comment: Give us input/output.

Comment: Your syntax is confuse, i think you forgot a `)`

Comment: also i think you must have a `+` or `-` before `'1 MONTH'::INTERVAL` please correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNC` gives the date excluding the time portion.

`TO_CHAR` with format mask gives you different parts of a date.

For example,

`to_char(sysdate, 'DD')` gives today's date as `09`.
`to_char(sysdate, 'MON')` gives current month as `OCT`.
`to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')` gives current year as `2014`.

Play around with the different formats. For a specific output, mention your desired output.

Look at datetime format models in documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm